# Get Session ID from website loaded in WebView control in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: session, xamarin, cookies, webview, xamarin.ios

I have literally just started developing iOS apps with Xamarin (Visual Studio 2017) within the last week, and while the documentation seems to be quite good on one hand, it's also really basic on the other.

I've been watching some content on Pluralsight which has given me some of the basics, but I've run into a brick wall while trying to find out how to access details of the session of a website loaded in a WebView control.

My code at the moment is very simple and I call the `WebView`'s `LoadRequest` method, passing in the url of the site I want to display. The site Url has been changed to protect the not so innocent...

```
var url = "https://MySslSite.com";
WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
```

As one of the developers of the site, I know it creates a custom session ID that I need the iOS app to have access to.

Using the Intellisense in Visual Studio, typing "WebView." gives me no properties or methods with the words "cookie" or "session" in there, and I can't see anything else that jumps out that would hint at accessing the data I need.

I have also added the following to get an array of cookies, and after adding a break point after this and watching the cookie array, I don't see anything there containing specific information about the data stored in the session (including the session ID).

```
NSHttpCookie[] cookies = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies;
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why I got downvoted on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access cookies once your website is loaded in WebView. So, You need to create a custom renderer for WebView. and, You can access cookies in **DidFinishNavigation** method. which is **IWKNavigationDelegate** method. So, you need to inherit it in your **CustomWebViewRenderer** class.

## Code

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>,IWKNavigationDelegate
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = new WKUserContentController() };
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                webView.NavigationDelegate = this;
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
        }

        [Export("webView:didFinishNavigation:")]
        public void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            NSHttpCookieStorage storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
            foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies)
            {
                storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
            }
            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said, these are my first steps into Xamarin development, and (unless I'm mistaken) it appears you've sent me on a wild goose chase here. Your answer seems to relate to Xamarin.Forms, where as my project was started using Xamarin.IOS.

Comment: Hi Pavan, I have managed to create the application in a Xamarin.Forms solution now, and have successfully created the CustomWebViewRenderer in the IOS project in the solution, along with the CustomWebView control in the root project. However, I have no clue where to put the LoadingFinished method, or how to make sure its called once the site is loaded. Can you help me understand where that should go, and how i call it once the site has loaded successfully?

Comment: LoadingFinished is UIWebViewDelegate's method. you need to inherit CustomWebViewRenderer by IUIWebViewDelegate. So, you can override the UIWebViewDelegate's methods in CustomWebViewRenderer.

Comment: @Karl, I have updated my answer, I have replaced UIWebView to WKWebView. and also add CustomWebViewRenderer code for ios.